# Extracting negative and positive unique values from a data-frame?

Tags: python, dataframe, dictionary, extract

I have a big data-frame with more than 300 features (columns) and 200000 rows. In this data-frame some of columns contain negative values and some no. An example of my data-frame is below:

```
    my_data:
         ID,  f1, f2, ...., f300
         x1,  34, 45, ....,  23
         x1,  5.4,56, ....,  32
         x2, -0.34,45,....,  12
         x2,   3,  56,....,  54
         x2,  56, 10, ....,  90
         x3,   5, -4, ....,  31
         x3,   30,6, ....,   4
         x4,  5.3,1.4,...,   0.4
         x4,  5.2,4.7,...,   3
         ...  ...   ...   ...
         Xn,  0.4,-5,...,    -3
```

Now, I want to extract the uniques Ids which contain only positive values and put it to another data frame, and also extract the unique Ids which contain at least one negative values and save it to another data-frame, something like this:

```
     my_pos_data:
         ID, f1, f2, ....., f300
         x1, 34, 45,....,    23
         x1, 5.4,56,...,     32
         x4, 5.3,1.4,...,   0.4
         x4, 5.2,4.7,...,    3


      my_neg_data:
         ID,   f1,  f2, ....., f300
         x2,  -0.34, 45, ...,   12
         x2,    3,   56,....,   54
         x2,    56,  10,...,    90
         x3,    5,   -4,...,    31
         x3,    30,   6,....,   4
         Xn,    0.4,  -5,...,   -3
```

I used the below code, but I only could extract the samples which contain negative and all positive values, not unique Ids.

```
     my_pos_data=my_data[(my_data.iloc[:,1:300] >= 0).all(1)]
     my_neg_data=my_data[(my_data.iloc[:,1:300] < 0).any(1)]
```

Indeed I want to extract the Ids which contained only positive values (for my_pos_data data frame). Any idea to do it in an efficient way?

Comment: Don't you mean that some rows contain negative values? And you want to extract x_i where i is the id of the given row?

Comment: I have edited the question